# Can't write Session variables on certain occasions?

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

For some reason session won't keep the variable stored. But when the browser is restarted it corrects the error. Why is this? Here is the warning... Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct () in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Try to handle session using database

Answer (score 2):

This is because the $_SESSION variables by PHP's set bath session.save_path. By using `phpinfo()` you can view that information. You can fix this error by setting the path, which is usually already set on linux machines. Just simply include `session_save_path(“/tmp”);` before your `session_start()` and this should fix this error...